# MVC post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, post

I have two Views with two different post method in different Controllers. Both methods are used to export data to an Excel file.

Here is my code structure:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // code for this action
    ExportToExcel(dd); // export from dataset
}

public void ExportToExcel(DataSet dd)
{
    // Code to export
}
```

My View page code looks like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("upload", "Test", FormMethod.Post,
        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <input type="file" name="file" id="files" multiple="multiple" />

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Export Excel" name="submit" />
        }
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a second post method in another controller that looks basically the same as the above code, with only slight differences.

How can I merge the two post methods into one, and use to export?

Comment: Put your `ExportToExcel()` method in a separate service and call it from each of your post methods

Comment: When i tried to do like that my data sets are empty @StephenMuecke

Comment: What datasets - you have not shown any relevant code. If `public void ExportToExcel(DataSet dd)` works in your controller, it also works in a separate service.